# Create jquery html object from rendering a rails partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am building a rails app and using datatables.net to display some data which can be added/removed through AJAX.

I have this rails partial which should be rendered and subsequently added to the datatable:

```
<tr id="<%= "device-" + device.id.to_s %>">
  <td class="device-id"><%= device.id %></td>
  <td class="device-devicetype-name"><%= device.device_type.name %></td>
  <td class="device-serial"><%= device.serial %></td>
  <td class="device-bought"><%= device.bought %></td>
  <td class="device-remarks"><%= device.remarks %></td>
  <td class="device-actions">
    <% if can? :manage, Rental %>
      <%= form_for(@rental.device_rentals.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :device_id, device.id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :rental_id, @rental.id %>
        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I then call the render function in the AJAX request response and try to add it to the table like so:

```
availableDevicesList = $('#available-devices-list').DataTable();

availableDevicesList.row.add($("<%= escape_javascript render('devices/available_devices_table_row', :device => @device).to_json %>")).draw();
```

This does not work, since the row doesn't end up getting added to the table. When I copy/paste the jquery part from the request response to the console and run it, I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &quot;\u003ctr id=\&quot;device-3\&quot;\u003e\n  \u003ctd class=\&quot;device-id\(...)
```

EDIT: This is what the JS Line gets rendered to in the response:

```
availableDevicesList.row.add($("\&quot;\\u003ctr id=\\\&quot;device-3\\\&quot;\\u003e\\n  \\u003ctd class=\\\&quot;device-id\\\&quot;\\u003e3\\u003c/td\\u003e\\n  \\u003ctd class=\\\&quot;device-devicetype-name\\\&quot;\\u003eBlack Case\\u003c/td\\u003e\\n  \\u003ctd class=\\\&quot;device-serial\\\&quot;\\u003eCASE0001\\u003c/td\\u003e\\n  \\u003ctd class=\\\&quot;device-bought\\\&quot;\\u003e01.12.2015\\u003c/td\\u003e\\n  \\u003ctd class=\\\&quot;device-remarks\\\&quot;\\u003eMaserati sticker\\u003c/td\\u003e\\n  \\u003ctd class=\\\&quot;device-actions\\\&quot;\\u003e\\n      \\u003cform class=\\\&quot;new_device_rental\\\&quot; id=\\\&quot;new_device_rental\\\&quot; action=\\\&quot;/device_rentals\\\&quot; accept-charset=\\\&quot;UTF-8\\\&quot; data-remote=\\\&quot;true\\\&quot; method=\\\&quot;post\\\&quot;\\u003e\\u003cinput name=\\\&quot;utf8\\\&quot; type=\\\&quot;hidden\\\&quot; value=\\\&quot;\\u0026#x2713;\\\&quot; /\\u003e\\u003cinput type=\\\&quot;hidden\\\&quot; name=\\\&quot;authenticity_token\\\&quot; value=\\\&quot;aiu/5qq8UVfPSCTvq3+VRsnXxwJS9agJuPIZTH1HXd3Y+ocFG7IhgB99P1UnTKfrhusw/vcO6vhSMnreDiVOSg==\\\&quot; /\\u003e\\n        \\u003cinput type=\\\&quot;hidden\\\&quot; name=\\\&quot;device_id\\\&quot; id=\\\&quot;device_id\\\&quot; value=\\\&quot;3\\\&quot; /\\u003e\\n        \\u003cinput type=\\\&quot;hidden\\\&quot; name=\\\&quot;rental_id\\\&quot; id=\\\&quot;rental_id\\\&quot; value=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot; /\\u003e\\n        \\u003cbutton name=\\\&quot;button\\\&quot; type=\\\&quot;submit\\\&quot; class=\\\&quot;btn btn-primary\\\&quot;\\u003e\\n          \\u003cspan class=\\\&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign\\\&quot;\\u003e\\u003c/span\\u003e\\n\\u003c/button\\u003e\\u003c/form\\u003e  \\u003c/td\\u003e\\n\\u003c/tr\\u003e\&quot;")).draw();
```

Comment: Does this help `<tr id="device-<%=device.id.to_s %>">`

Comment: @Abhi No, it still fails. I added what the line in my JS response gets rendered to in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I solved it, another question here on stackoverflow stated that this error may be a problem with the encoding of the string. Adapting the solution I found there led me to this, which works:

```
var deviceTableRow = "";
deviceTableRow += "<%= escape_javascript render('devices/rental_devices_table_row', :device => @device) %>";
rentalDevicesList.row.add($(deviceTableRow)).draw();
```